# WSO2 API Manager (4.2.0) - Setting Up a Monitoring Dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm currently using the open-source version of wso2am-4.2.0 and I'm seeking a dashboard integration for the effective monitoring of API calls. While considering options, I discovered that Choreo could serve this purpose, but it's not open-source and operates as a SAAS solution. Are there any recommended on-premises solutions or integrations available for analytics and monitoring that align with functionalities similar to previous versions of APIM (which had the option of integrating a separate analytics server)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [ELK](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/) and [Datadog](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/datadog-installation-guide/) for this

Comment: Hi @chamila thanks for the response. Is there a guide to setup the same in a Kubernetes cluster?